# IMobileServiceSyncTable.PurgeAsync condition against the server?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, cloud, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use IMobileServiceSyncTable.PurgeAsync to clear my local sqlllite tables from unnecessary data. My problem is that the condition passed to IMobileServiceSyncTable.PurgeAsync only seems to work against the local database ("Delete all records in the local table which apply to this condition").

But what i want is: "Delete all records in the local table if the server version of this record apply to this condition".

I dont want to pull the new server version before i can delete the local version.

Comment: As you said that `PurgeAsync` is used to deal with the items in the local table. As I known, you need to pull the items from the associated remote table firstly. Moreover, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I think I must rethink my general approach